# Duda con SetFocus()

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio y me pone que tengo que usar `setFocus()` para seleccionar el contenido de un cuadro y que gane el foco. Luego usar el `selectAll()` para seleccionarlo.  Pero no entiendo nada.

¿Alguien puede explicarme con un ejemplo como funciona?

Es decir, tengo una caja `X` y cuando me dé algún error tengo que señalarla con `selectAll()` y luego hacer `setFocus()`.

El programa lo estoy haciendo con Java - SWT a través de WindowsBuilder.

Comment: Hola @Montse. Por favor indica con qué tecnología trabajas: swing, awt, JavaFX, etc.

Comment: Perdón pero está a etiqueta de Java pensaba que con eso era suficiente. Tecnologia pues SWT

Comment: Sucede que no, existen varios frameworks para crear pantallas visuales en Java.

Comment: No tenía ni idea. Voy a buscar un poco de info sobre los diferentes FrameWorks para que no me vuelva a pasar y edito pregunta gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucionado, pongo una parte de mi código:

```
if(data.probarEquiv1()==3) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error a Primera Divisa");
    PrimeraDivisaTXT.setFocus(); 
    PrimeraDivisaTXT.selectAll(); 
}
```

Es decir el cuadro al que queremos hacer focus `PrimeraDivisaTXT`

Este código lo que hace es que si el usuario cuando introduce el dato `Equiv1` lo introduce mal el sistema le avisa con un `JOptionPane` de que existe un error y entonces toma el foco en el cuadro donde está el error (es decir el cuadro `PrimeraDivisaTXT`)